# Why is capacitance CdB calculated like this? (Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits- Behzad Razavi” book Chapter 6 Exercise 6.4)

Tags: analog, design

I know formula CDB=CSB=WECj+2*（W+E）Cjsw. I know how to answer it. But, I don't know how the parameters are derived, not in Tables 2-1.  I don't know how to solve the problem.  Can you help me?

The question is like this:

[image]

The reference answer is calculated as follows:

[image]